# Keep button properties after page reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

Hi I'm trying to set button properties in html when it's clicked and when it's not, those changes works fine when the page isn't reload. 
I want to keep button properties after page reload, o if the button was clicked and then the page was reloaded the button needs to keep selected.

I've made this example in html to show what I've got

```
<button id="btntext" class="k-button" onclick="clickEvent(this.id, 't2')" onmousemove="imgChange(this.id, 't2', 't')"  onmouseout="imgChange(this.id, 't','t2')"><img id= "icon" class="k-image" alt="text" src="../images/t2.png" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; vertical-align:inherit" hspace="7"/>Text</button>
```

there is also a script witch change img on click or mouse move (imgChange) but it doesn't works as I need.

Answer (score 4):

Look there are two solutions for this;
1.client side solution
2.server side solution

1.client side solution

a. Use localStorage or sessionStorage,e.g,

Consider your html;

```
 <button id="somebutton" style="color:red" onclick=click()>Some Button</button>
```

Now the JS:

```
 function click(){
      $("#somebutton").css("color","green");
      localStorage.setItem("btncolor","green");
 }
```

And on document load

```
 window.onload=function()
 {
      $("#somebutton").css("color",localStorage.getItem("btncolor"));
 }
```

2.server side solution

Call ajax on button click to save button state in server side and on window.onload call another ajax to get the state from server side.

Comment: Can I set an Item to localStorage the first time the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes,you can. in windows.onload function write localStorage.setItem("key","val")

Comment: I've used localStorage in Script functions inside HTML document, but window.onload doesn't work there, does it only works on the JS?

Comment: Post your code or make a fiddle and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Use localstorage variable and set it true or false.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

U can set the variable in javascript and bind to the html.